# search and replace in a json by php

Tags: php, json, search

I have a json like below :

```
{"fav":[{"id":14823},{"id":14817},{"id":14811},{"id":14775}],"scheduled":[{"id":14811},{"id":14817}]}
```

I want to search scheduled in fav, if it exist, it will be removed in fav

The result which I want as :

```
 {"fav":[{"id":14823},{"id":14775}],"scheduled":[{"id":14811},{"id":14817}]}
```

Comment: Please help me if you find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Use json_decode to have it in a neat format, and then just compare the values of the arrays. Check out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

After you decode the JSON:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

You can use array_diff to remove the values in `fav` that are also in `scheduled`.

```
$fav = array_values(array_diff(
    array_column($data['fav'], 'id'),
    array_column($data['scheduled'], 'id')));
```

(The `array_values` is necessary because `array_diff` will preserve the keys, and you'll need sequential zero-indexed keys for reencoding to JSON to work properly.)

Then map those values back to the `{id: value}` format and reassign the result to `$data['fav']`.

```
$data['fav'] = array_map(function($item){ return ['id' => $item]; }, $fav);
```

Then, obviously, reencode as JSON.

```
$json = json_encode($data);
```